# Why are my JavaScript files only showing in bundles in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, bundling-and-minification

I am running two projects using very similar bases.  They are both bundling the same JS files, but when I am debugging one it show the Source of the JS files in source in Chrome Developer tools, but the other only shows the bundled files.  Any ideas why this might be?

Scripts:

[image: Scripts load]

Bundles:

[image: Only Bundles load]

Comment: How are you serving them .? Server configuration .?

Comment: Hard to say from the almost nothing we know about your project. Is there a map file missing from one project? Do you have more than one build type?

Comment: My guess is your backend is C# .NET.  I do a lot with MVC in C# and, out of the box, it usually has a bundleconfig file.  If that's not the case, let me know, I'm interested.  The only time I see this is when I'm using a backend like C# to serve a bundled js.  It's great for users.  You can however opt not to bundle them, to just serve them as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: at the bottom of the BundleConfig we had mandated:

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Removed this and can view source now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your backend is C# .NET.  I do a lot with MVC in C# and, out of the box, it usually has a bundleconfig file.  If that's not the case, let me know, I'm interested.  The only time I see this is when I'm using a backend like C# to serve a bundled js.  It's great for users.  You can however opt not to bundle them, to just serve them as-is.

Again on a great assumption that this is a C# MVC project or something similar, and not something else, here's what the bundle will look like in the layout/view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
```

Or something like that.  I always customize mine some.  To serve them unbundled for testing just comment that out and create your regular old  tags.

Again going here purely on assumptions, so let us know more about your environment.